# How to get Wifi working an Raspberry PI 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 for ARM

Tags: wifi, ubuntu, systemd-networkd

### Short story

PI is not connecting via Wifi. Errors of systemd-journal below:

*journalctl -n*

```c
ubuntu kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: scan error (-84)
ubuntu wpa_supplicant[573]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-84 retry=1
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-84
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
ubuntu kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_run_escan: error (-84)
ubuntu kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: scan error (-84)
ubuntu wpa_supplicant[573]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-84 retry=1
```

### Long Story

**System**
Rasberry PI 4
Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS for ARM -> Installed with the Raspberry PI Imager v1.7.2

**What works**
I get the headless connection working over LAN-Cable.

**The Problem**
The PI does not connect over Wifi to my router.

**What I checked**

1. rfkill is not blocking
2. the ssid name and password is correct
3. systemd-networkd.service is running
4. systemd-resolved.service is running
5. wpa_supplicant is running
6. System Updates -> sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt get upgrade -y
7. The Access Point is 1 Meter away and Others clients can Connect to it
8. cloudinit is disabled
9. "Fast Roaming" is disabled in the router

I did a complete fresh install of the system and modified the wifi settings in the file network-config. It is in the root directory of the sd card.

Then after this didn't work, I did check:

*sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml*

```c
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                "a":
                    password: "xxx---xxxxx"
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
```

The " signs were not present, so i added them like in the code above,

Then I applied the changes and rebooted:

```
sudo netplan generate && sudo netplan apply && sudo reboot
```

*journalctl -n*

```c
ubuntu kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: scan error (-84)
ubuntu wpa_supplicant[573]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-84 retry=1
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: sdio ctrlframe tx failed err=-84
ubuntu kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
ubuntu kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_run_escan: error (-84)
ubuntu kernel: ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_scan: scan error (-84)
ubuntu wpa_supplicant[573]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-84 retry=1
```

*cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-wlan0.network*

```
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=600
UseMTU=true
```

*cat /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eth0.network*

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
```

*ip a*

```c
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e4:5f:01:5d:19:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

journalctl -u wpa_supplicant

```c
Apr 19 10:12:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
Apr 19 10:12:42 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
Apr 19 10:12:42 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[928]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 16 09:18:47 ubuntu systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 09:18:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:18:49 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[40479]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 16 09:18:49 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
May 16 09:18:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:18:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 09:18:56 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped WPA supplicant.
-- Boot 59f5183b303c48e2bee2b82cb69ef775 --
May 16 09:19:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:19:06 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[693]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 16 09:19:06 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
May 16 09:26:40 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:26:40 ubuntu systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 09:26:40 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped WPA supplicant.
-- Boot 8f8fa7de4caa4e34940b117bccd9e9c9 --
May 16 09:26:50 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:26:50 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
May 16 09:26:50 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[757]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 16 09:37:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:37:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant.service: Deactivated successfully.
May 16 09:37:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped WPA supplicant.
-- Boot f9af87f1bcd54228a38cbc498903522e --
May 16 09:38:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:38:01 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[760]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 16 09:38:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
```

*journalctl -u systemd-networkd.service*

```c
-- Boot 59f5183b303c48e2bee2b82cb69ef775 --
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Network Configuration...
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: wlan0: Link UP
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: lo: Link UP
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: lo: Gained carrier
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: Enumeration completed
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: wlan0: Link DOWN
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Network Configuration.
May 16 09:18:59 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: wlan0: Link UP
May 16 09:19:04 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: eth0: Link UP
May 16 09:19:08 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: eth0: Gained carrier
May 16 09:19:10 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
May 16 09:19:12 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 10.1.1.40/24 via 10.1.1.1
May 16 09:26:40 ubuntu systemd-networkd[637]: eth0: DHCP lease lost
May 16 09:26:40 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopping Network Configuration...
```

*systemctl status wpa_supplicant*

```c
● wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-16 09:38:01 UTC; 19min ago
   Main PID: 760 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4416)
     Memory: 936.0K
        CPU: 26ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/wpa_supplicant.service
             └─760 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant

May 16 09:38:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting WPA supplicant...
May 16 09:38:01 ubuntu wpa_supplicant[760]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
May 16 09:38:01 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant.
```

*systemctl status systemd-networkd*

```c
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-16 09:37:54 UTC; 20min ago
TriggeredBy: ● systemd-networkd.socket
       Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
   Main PID: 703 (systemd-network)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4416)
     Memory: 2.8M
        CPU: 291ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-networkd.service
             └─703 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd

May 16 09:37:54 ubuntu systemd-networkd[703]: lo: Link UP
May 16 09:37:54 ubuntu systemd-networkd[703]: lo: Gained carrier
```

*systemctl status systemd-resolved.service*

```c
● systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-05-16 09:37:54 UTC; 22min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients
   Main PID: 705 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 4416)
     Memory: 8.4M
        CPU: 314ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─705 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
```

*ls /sys/class/net*

```c
eth0  lo  wlan0
```

***Resources I used:***

1. Linux Service Management Made Easy with systemd by Donald A. Tevault (Author)
2. https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Netplan/
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzCJK_OqFH0

Comment: Ubuntu server does not use WiFi (for good reasons). I added a GUI to Server, which installed NetworkManager (and WiFi support). This is not a specific Pi problem - try Unix & Linux or a Ubuntu site, as the `systemd-networkd` is general.

Comment: NOTE it is extremely unlikely Ubuntu has `wlan0`  what does `ls /sys/class/net` show?

Comment: *ls /sys/class/net* ```eth0  lo  wlan0```

Comment: Are you using a generic ARM Ubuntu image or the one for the Pi specifically? The one specifically for the Pi worked out of the box for me on my Pi 3B+, after simply adding the SSID+password to the Netplan config file and applying the configuration. I followed these instructions: https://tttapa.github.io/Pages/Raspberry-Pi/Installation+Setup/WiFi-Setup.html

Comment: @tttapa Yes I do use the generic ARM Ubuntu image, installed with the "Raspberry PI Imager"